# How to refresh react navigation header - multi-language issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to integrate multi-language inside my react native app using "i18n-js": "^3.2.1"
I would like to update the header from react-navigation after changing the locale of i18n.

Once the locale is change, i am running this.forceUpdate();
to reload the page.

```js
switchSettings = (field_name, value) => {
        console.log(field_name);
        switch (field_name) {
            case "languages": 
                setLanguage(value[0])
                this.forceUpdate();
                break;

            default: 
                break;
        }
    }
```

this works well for my custom components however, this is not updating my react navigation header title/back-button :\

is there anything available with react-navigation to re-render the header or something to re-evaluate the navigationOptions?

I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks

EDIT1:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerTitle: i18n.t('title')
        }
    };
```

The above is working fine when I am going on the next page, but if I go back, the navigationOptions is not re-evaluate

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the navigation headers by updating the theme object. To do this I include the locale in the theme. Here is some sample Typescript code:

```
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  NavigationContainer,
  Theme,
} from '@react-navigation/native'

...

export function Navigation({ darkMode }: Props) {
  const { locale } = useLocale() // a custom hook to get locale from a context

  type ThemeWithLocale = Theme & {
    locale: string | undefined
  }

  const theme: ThemeWithLocale = {
    locale,
    ...(darkMode ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme),
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Root />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: did exactly this, but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

The routes and the `navigationOptions` that you define when declaring the router are set when the app is launched. So they won't change when the language prop is updated. What you can do is add `static navigationOptions` **inside** your screen component and define the title there.

For eg.

```
static navigationOptions = {
     title: this.props.language : "en"? "English title": "Other language title",
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,
I do the following on each screen: (I have EDIT 1 my question)

but when I am going to the previous page, this is not re-evaluated.

What is the difference between your way and my way?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you changing the language on this screen and the going back to previous screen? If that's the case, your previous screen in the stack (assuming you are using the `StackNavigator`) won't rerender. Do this by globally saving the current language (for eg. using [redux](https://redux.js.org/) ) and using the props as I suggested. 
Best would be to use a library built for `react-native`. Check this [library](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n)